# Conditionally creating new variables for data manipulation

Tags: performance, r

My problem is related to data manipulation: on the basis of the existing variables in a given data set, I would like to create new ones. Bonus points for performance as well as code readability.

Let's consider a reproducible example for the famous "iris" data set. My goal is to create a new variable, which can be described by the following set of conditions:

1. if species="setosa" or species="virginica" and sepal.length < 5 then
       new variable = "Species1",
2. if (species="setosa" or species="virginica") and 5<= sepal.length <
   10 then new variable = "Species2",
3. if (species="setosa" or species="virginica") and sepal.length >= 10
   then new variable = "Species3",
4. otherwise, new variable = species (in this case "versicolor").

In order to achieve this, I have written the following conditional instructions:

```
iris$Speciec2 <- ifelse(iris$Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"),
                       ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length < 5, "Species1",
                              ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5 & iris$Sepal.Length < 7,
                                     "Species2", "Species3")), as.character(iris$Species))
```

and it's really hard to read. I wonder if there are any better solutions.

Comment: Variably-named variables are rarely a good idea. But what are you _really_ trying to accomplish? It's hard to help you when you're asking to have just one line of code reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a couple easy changes to improve readability. First, use `with` or `transform` so you don't have to carry a lot of `iris$`. Second, reorganize your logical tests so each nested `ifelse` appear in the "if-false" part of the previous `ifelse`, not in the "if-true" part. Hopefully, this will make sense:

```
iris$Speciec2 <- with(iris,
  ifelse(!Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"), as.character(Species),
  ifelse(Sepal.Length < 5,                       "Species1",
  ifelse(Sepal.Length < 7,                       "Species2",
                                                 "Species3")))
)
```

I think it reads a lot easier this way, where each line contains a test and the output value if the test is passed. If the test fails, we move onto the next line. And at the end, the last line contains the value if all tests have failed. I also like this layout because it looks a lot like how you would nest Perl's ternary operator:

```
result = condition1 ? value_if_condition1_is_true
       : condition2 ? value_if_condition2_is_true
       : condition3 ? value_if_condition3_is_true
       :              value_if_condition3_is_false
```

Another solution would be to use the `cut` or `findInterval` functions to handle the conditions you have on `Sepal.Length`. These functions become really handy when you have many cases ("breaks") in mind, although here you only have three. You could do:

```
new_labels <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = c(-Inf, 5, 7, +Inf), 
                  labels = paste0("Species", 1:3), right = FALSE)
iris$Speciec2 <- with(iris, ifelse(Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"),
                                   as.character(new_labels),
                                   as.character(Species)))
```

---

Now about performance, since you mentioned it. Know that `ifelse` and `cut` are vectorized functions so unless you are handling many millions of rows or doing some high frequency trading, you should be fine :-)

Minor speed improvements might be made by replacing the `ifelse` with in-place replacements (`x[idx] <- value`), I let you decide if this is more readable:

```
iris$Speciec2 <- with(iris, {
  res <- as.character(Species)
  need_change <- Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica")
  res[need_change & Sepal.Length < 5]                     <- "Species1"
  res[need_change & Sepal.Length >= 5 & Sepal.Length < 7] <- "Species2"
  res[need_change & Sepal.Length >= 7]                    <- "Species3"
  res
})
```

Finally, switching to a `data.table` (from the R package of the same name) is always recommended when dealing with large size data.frames and when speed is a concern.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not consider the "cut" function!

Answer (score 0):

If concerned by performance consider `data.table`.

Here as a quick and dirty implementation:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- iris
setDT(dt)

setDT(dt)[Species != "versicolor" & Sepal.Length < 5, 
          new.var := "Species1"]
setDT(dt)[Species != "versicolor" & Sepal.Length >=5 & Sepal.Length < 10,  
          new.var := "Species2"]
setDT(dt)[Species != "versicolor" & Sepal.Length >= 10, 
          new.var := "Species3"]
setDT(dt)[is.na(new.var), 
          new.var := "Species"]
```